# VueJS 3 / Django : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@revolist/vue3-datagrid". Relative references must start with either "/"

Tags: django, vue.js

I use Django 4.0 and a Vue JS 3 on an app where I need a Vue Module called @revolist/vue3-datagrid.

On the documentation, this is how I'm supposed to call it into my template file ([doc here](https://revolist.github.io/revogrid/guide/framework.vue.overview.html#vue-3)).

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-grid
      theme="compact"
      :source="rows"
      :columns="columns"
    ></v-grid>
  </div>
</template>
 
<script>
import VGrid from "@revolist/vue3-datagrid";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      columns: [{ prop: "name" }, { prop: "details" }],
      rows: [{
        name: "1",
        details: "Item 1",
      }]
    };
  },
  components: {
    VGrid,
  },
};
</script>
```

When I copy pasted it into my template file on my Django App, I've got this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@revolist/vue3-datagrid". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

After some searches, I've found that adding

```
<script type="module">
```

could help. It didn't work for me.

I guess that the documentation is written for Node.JS or pure Vue JS 3 apps, not Django-like ones. I think that Vue is not able to find "@revolist/vue3-datagrid", since my node_modules files is in **/static/node_modules/**@revolist/vue3-datagrid directory.

[image]

So, I tried to call the import that way :

```
import VGrid from "/static/node_modules/@revolist/vue3-datagrid/dist/vgrid.js";
```

But I've got this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/static/node_modules/@revolist/vue3-datagrid/dist/vgrid.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

I'm not sure that's this file I must import.
More generally, how I'm supposed to handle this kind of import into a non-VueJS app.

Could someone explain me how to deal with it ?

Many thanks !

Comment: did you try: import VGrid from "/static/node_modules/@revolist/vue3-datagrid" ?

Comment: I've got a 404 error :(

Comment: ok your problem is that you don't build your vue app . Later in the future we will be able to use <script type="module">, but it's a bit early for now. 
Make your life easier, separate front and back end in different projects.
Learn how to build a vue app and put the compiled files in your static django folder